# React - When to use hooks, and when to use HOCs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When do we should use hooks over HOCs, and HOCs over hooks in React?

For example, I can perfectly have a hook for managing auth state, and then use it in a component... but I can also have a HOC which manages the auth state and wrap components for using its logic.

So... is there any rule to know if what interests you is to implement a HOC or a hook?

Comment: I thought this might be a good read
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-higher-order-components-hocs-7ae4a08b7b58

Answer (score 2):

**Why use HOC?**

HOC is useful when you want to inject additional behaviors into the existing Component. You can use HOC to inject:

- React Lifecycle (eg. execute code in componentWillMount)
- State
  (eg. react-redux’s connect) 3
- Component (Parent Component, Child
  Component, Sibling Component) Style

**Why React Hook?**

If you write a function component, and then you want to add some state to it, previously you do this by converting it to a class. But, now you can do it by using a Hook inside the existing function component.

Comment: And what is the difference between injecting a state with a HOC, and using a hook inside a component? I mean, in both cases the logic is out of the component.

Comment: I mean, the difference from moving state management to a custom hook and to a HOC.